# Data not rendering on View after routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, service

I am not able to get the data on the view after routing while the same is available on the console. Moreover if the view is not changed the data is visible.Also if i call the service on view , i am able to get the data.

controller.js:

```
myStore.controller("Home", function ($scope, StoreService, $log, $window,$location ){
    var onComplete = function (data) {
        $log.info(data);

        $scope.gettempdata = data;
        $log.info($scope.gettempdata);
        $log.info("in complete");
    }
    var onError = function (reason) {
        alert(reason.errorcode);
    }
$scope.GetItemsByCat = function (CatName, loc)
    {
        $log.info("wait for 5 more secs");
        viewPage(loc);
        StoreService.getItemsByCat(CatName).then(onComplete, onError);


    }
});
```

App.js:

```
var myStore = angular.module('groceries', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
  when("/Home", {
            templateUrl: "/Index.html",
            controller: "Home"
        }).
    when("/Items", {
        templateUrl: "Store/Fruits.html",
        controller: "Home"
    }).
 otherwise
    ({
        redirectTo: "/Home"
    })

});
```

View:

```
<p class="text-info">
        <b>Welcome to our store.
        <br />
            We have the below categories JUST FOR YOU. Please select one to get more details on the items</b>

    </p>


{{gettempdata}}

        <table class="table table-bordered">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="/img/Fruit.png" height="60" width="60" alt="Fruits" />

                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" ng-click="GetItemsByCat('Fruit',window.location.href='/Items')">Fruits</a>
                    <!--<a href="" ng-click="GetItemsByCat('Fruit')">Fruits</a>-->

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="/img/Vegetable.png" height="60" width="60" alt="Vegies" /></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" ng-click="GetItemsByCat('Vegetable')">Vegetables</a>
                </td>

            </tr>

        </table>
```

Data in console:

[image]

Comment: Both routes have same controller.

Comment: There are 3 problems here: 1) You don't need a "Home" controller b/c it doesn't do anything that's needed in the Home view. 2) Don't use ng-click, just link to the url. 3) call the method "GetItemsByCat" in your controller. If you post a plnkr with some code, I can show you what I mean.

Comment: @o4ohel can you please explain . It will take me some time to create a plunker working template for it.

Comment: @Iquery Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/28DCsSQtElcdM86N9hus?p=preview) that should illustrate the concepts: http://plnkr.co/edit/28DCsSQtElcdM86N9hus?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use the router to use the views/controllers and to add params.
Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/28DCsSQtElcdM86N9hus?p=preview) that illustrates these concepts:
http://plnkr.co/edit/28DCsSQtElcdM86N9hus?p=preview

Script:

```
var myStore = angular.module('groceries', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'home.html'})
    .when('/items/:catName', {templateUrl: 'items.html', controller: 'ItemsCtrl'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'})
  });

myStore.controller('ItemsCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, StoreService) {
  var catName = $routeParams.catName
  var onComplete = function (data) {
    $scope.items = data;
  },
  onError = function (reason) {
    alert(reason.errorcode);
  };
  $scope.GetItemsByCat = function (catName) {
    StoreService.getItemsByCat(catName).then(onComplete, onError);
  };
  $scope.GetItemsByCat(catName);
});

myStore.factory('StoreService', function($q) {
  function getItemsByCat(catName) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {

      deferred.resolve([catName + ': item1', catName + ': item2', catName + ': item3']);
    }, 1000);

    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return {
    getItemsByCat: getItemsByCat
  };
});
```

MARKUP (app):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="groceries">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

MARKUP (main):

```
<h2>Welcome to our store.</h2>
<p>We ...</p>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="/img/Fruit.png" height="60" width="60" alt="Fruits" /></td>
    <td><a href="#/items/Fruits">Fruits</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="/img/Vegetable.png" height="60" width="60" alt="Vegies" /></td>
    <td>
      <a href="#/items/Vegetables">Vegetables</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

MARKUP (items):

```
<h4>Items</h4>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
<div><a href="#/home">Back</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its always preferred to have a separate controller per view and i would recommend the same here.
Also, before checking anything else, debug your code and check if the debugger is getting a hit when your view is loaded and data is getting bound to your scope variable. If everything works fine, try using $scope.apply() to refresh your view.

What does "viewPage" function do? Does it redirect to the new view? Try using just one view (may be merge the contents in a single view) and controller and see if it works instead of two views bound to same controller.

Comment: Thanks @Piyush Khanna. i created seperate controllers for each view.and used RouteParams as mentioned in answer above ..
ViewPage was created for routing.